# p5.serialserver (i.e. p5serial and p5.serialcontrol) leaking memory

Tags: node.js, macos, p5.js

I'm trying to use p5.serial to display my Arduino-like device's USB output on a web page.  It generates about ten strings a second continually.

### the problem:

When I run p5serial (in a shell window) or [p5.serialcontrol](https://github.com/vanevery/p5.serialcontrol) (an Electron/GUI app), the node server starts out at ~ 12 MB, but as it runs it bloats quickly to > 1 GB and the output becomes sluggish.  The server eventually dies with

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
...
Abort trap: 6
```

### the question:

Is this a known issue (aside from the bug report I just filed)?  Or perhaps an error in the way I'm using it?

### some details:

When I connect the Arduino-like device via a serial USB terminal, things work just fine (except for the lack of lovely p5.js graphics).

I'm running OS X (10.12.6 / Sierra), node v6.3.0, p5.serialserver@0.0.24

[I've posted a gist containing a minimal example](https://gist.github.com/rdpoor/42829a3d224a151172e1b9668468bfbb) (but understand that it assumes you have an Arduino-like device with USB).

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: @KevinWorkman - I've posted a gist that strives to be minimal and verifiable (see updated text).  As for completeness, I'll have to assume you've got the hardware to replicate the test!  :)

Answer (score 0):

This memory link was fixed in p5.serial: https://github.com/p5-serial/p5.serialcontrol/issues/12

Comment: Is there a version number that's it's fixed in? Like v0.0.28?

Comment: Should be fixed in v0.0.25